# Setting up WordPress plugin's page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I recently published a WordPress plugin but all the links of plugin page (Description, Installation, FAQs, Screenshots etc) has same two line description I used in readme.txt. Although, I properly filled up the [readme.txt template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt). But it is not picking up anything else except description.

[image: plugin description showing in changelog too]

Comment: Ok, but what's the link to the plugin? So we can see the svn files...

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/twitter-bootstrap-collapse-aka-accordian-shortcode/

Comment: I took a [snapshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vwOLm.png). Consider adding it to the Question, so it is clear what happened.

Comment: Consider validating your readme.txt using readme.txt validator http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/validator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting bug you provoked out there :)

The only thing I see missing is the "short description" located between the `License URI` and the `==Description==` block.

It is used in the Header area:
[image]

While you are at it, take a look at this article: [The Plugins directory and readme.txt files](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/09/the-plugins-directory-and-readme-txt-files/). And also this one about [Header Images and screenshots](http://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/09/13/last-december-we-added-header-images-to-the/).

Comment: Putting the short description fixed it.